# jquery autocomplete not working for more than one result

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, zend-framework2

i'm using zend framwork 2 .

my function work fine when i catch one result from my database .. but when i use it for more than one result it don't work

my php function which i call :

```
public function autocompletesearch()
{

    $name = $_POST["q"]  ;

    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('name' => $name));
    $data = $rowset;

        $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
                'data' =>json_encode($data)
        ));
        $viewModel->setTerminal(true);

        return $viewModel;

 }
```

and here is my script :

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                delay: 500,
                minLength: 5,
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.get('/modul/autocompletesearch', { q : request.term }, function(data) {
                       response(data.split('\n'));

                    });
                }
            });
```

when i catch one result using $rowset->current() it work fine !!!

any suggestions ?

Comment: Try splitting your problem: First do you get more than one result if you run that function "autocompletesearch" manually. Second, try using your web developer console in i.e Chrome (F12) and see what (if any) data comes through when ajax-ing. And lastly, have you tried other autocompletes, and are you sure the one you're using is not faulty?

Comment: thanks for responding @bakkelun  ..  its work fine when i catch one result using rowset->current(), the autocompletesearch also work fine !

Comment: From what @bakkelun has said, could you post here the request.term value and the response from the ajax call for both a single result and multi result search?

Comment: when i get multiple result i can see the result using chrome inspect element .. 

response : {"data":["661","660","265","362","479","394","495"]}

Comment: Well there you have it. You are splitting the data on \n (newline) instead of comma (,) !. Try doing response(data.split(',')).

Comment: I jumped the gun with my answer there :). But with that result might you try response(JSON.parse(data)) as you are getting valid JSON back? just a thought

Comment: THANK YOU @bakkelun TotalWipeOut  your answers resolve my problem .. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just formalising the comments into an actual answer:

Change this line:

```
response(data.split('\n'));
```

to this:

```
response(JSON.parse(data));
```

to correctly parse the response into a JS array/object.